# Verilog: How to define range of values as a single condition in case statement?

Tags: verilog

I want to describe large multiplexer with over 200 cases and each case containinig tens of values. Some example cases:

```
9000 - 9029 : addr <= 0;
9030 - 9065 : addr <= 1;
9066 - 9131 : addr <= 2;
...
```

Is there any way to describe it similarly to VHDL

```
when 9000  to 9027  => addr_int <= 0;
```

or SystemVerilog's `case(value) inside`?

I couldn't find anything like that, only solutions are separating individual values with commas or use 'casez' with '?' and both are out of question - whole range is 7000 values and ranges aren't regular.

I'm rather new to verilog and any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in Verilog using a `case` statement. You'd have to use a sequence of `if`...`else` statements instead.

```
if ((value >=9000) && (value<=9029))
  addr <= 0;
else if ((value >=9030) && (value<=9065))
  addr <= 0;
else if ((value >=9066) && (value<=9131))
  addr <= 0;
else ...
```

A `case` statement in Verilog is basically the same as a sequence of `if`...`else` statements anyway.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.
Does it mean both statements in verilog infers priority routing network? That's what I'd like to avoid in that size.

Comment: Yes. The branches of a Verilog `case` statement do not have to mutually exclusive. Consequently, there is priority: the first branch that matches wins. So, your logic synthesiser will synthesise priority logic with a case statement. If you want it not to, then you have to embed synthesiser commands in comments (eg `//synopsys parallel_case`. In SystemVerilog, however, there is a built-in keyword that enforces mutual exclusivity: `unique`.

Comment: Ok, that makes things clear. I think I'll try out separate and parallel comparators and sum of results. If that doesn't work like I expect, then I'll play with synthesiser commands. Thanks for help.

Comment: just for completeness, in system verilog you could also use label ranges within the `case inside` statement: `case (sel) inside [9000 : 9092]: add <= 0; ...`.

Comment: I'd like to add that here it's not really easy to say will you have the same thing synthesized. If your case is full case, than you'll have one big mux, but if your case is not full case you will have a bunch of two input muxes. With ifs you will any how have a bunch of muxes

Please be careful here, that you will connect 200 muxes and be careful that every MUX has its own delay time that depends on tech and this could influence max freq of the system.

At the end, why don't you write Python script that will write this code for you?
I'm referring to full case here